# IE Hanging on jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Here's another clichéd problem, but I couldn't find an exact match to this.
I haven't posted any source here, as you can freely see all that is there on the link. :-)

**Statement**:I have a [web page](http://agrimgupta.com/antaragni/) at http://agrimgupta.com/antaragni/

**Disclaimer**: Pardon me for the pathetic coding on that page. **;-)** It was done on a very short interval. Improvements will be done at a later stage.

**Observation**: This page is functioning normally on my localhost on all browsers.

**Problem**: IE 8 is crawling (nearly hanging) while loading this page from the website. Although it is working fine on localhost. When on the website, It fails to render the mouseover effects, doing them in almost what seems like a minute.

**Question**: How to resolve this stuck up of IE? It is necessary to resolve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Instead of `if ($.browser.msie)`, which for example is wrong for IE9, you should use `if (!$.support.opacity)` :)

Comment: @Nick Its still hanging on my machine. :( Whats troubling me even more that is is doing fine on IE when on localhost. Ah. IE.

Comment: @Orange - Oh that won't solve the hanging problem, that's just best practice and future-proofing...though try removing that png fix statement and see what happens...

Comment: @Nick Haha! Removing it Stops IE from hanging. But then again, the transparencies go crash. ;) You got any other way to fix that PNG issue in IE?

Comment: IE8 supports PNG transparency. So does IE7.

Comment: Try changing the fadeIn and fadeOut's to just show() and hide()

Comment: @Pointy It sure does. But It is not doing so when using any jQuery effect.

Comment: @ZippyV That still maintains the problem. I guess the problem is with the PNG transparency fix, as Nick's comment helped out in that discovery

Comment: @OrangeRind oh yes that's true - the "opacity" stuff collides with the jQuery support and it totally doesn't work. Truly stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO

first of all use CSS where possible like here

```
    $('#downloadsglow').hide();
    $('#blogglow').hide();
    $('#eventsglow').hide();
    $('#galleryglow').hide();
```

to

```
#downloadsglow, #blogglow , #eventsglow , #galleryglow { display:none }
```

or at least do this `$('#downloadsglow,#blogglow,#eventsglow,#galleryglow').hide();`

then make sure all the images are loaded before starting observing the mouseover!

something like

```
$(window).load(
    function() {
        // weave your magic here.
    }
);
```

then use the holy grail of png fix

> - http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

like this

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script src="DD_belatedPNG.js"></script>
<script>
  DD_belatedPNG.fix('.pngimg');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Last but not least, since your site make use of a lot of PNG images i reccomend you to compress it, take a look at

> - http://www.aboutonlinetips.com/optimize-and-compress-png-files/

Comment: I did not get the part of your answer where "if($('#background img')....". Please explain a bit more there. :)

Comment: oh, sure. will try this :) :). But now I need to sleep. Its 6 in the morning, and IE has given me my first "Web" night-out. :|

Answer (score 1):

Invalid HTML can cause your page to render slow. Fix the unclosed `<link>` tag on line 8 and try again.
http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2fagrimgupta.com%2fantaragni%2f

Comment: Did it.
But the problem still persists.
Has it got to do with any part of the js code?